# SQL query returns no result from Java although it returns a result in Access

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

When I run this query:

```
select character from tbl_Unknown where format(fw,'.###')='48.143' and code='0001'
```

it returns a result in the Access query interface but when I try to run it from Java it doesn't return a result.

My table (tbl_Unknown):

```
char_id: autonumber   value:1
fw: short text        value:'48.1425'   Hint:after format it become '48.143'.
code: short text      value:'0001' 
character: short text value: 'x'
```

My java code:

```
public static String getLostedCharacter(String font,String fw, String code) {
      Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
      String character = null;
       try {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "select character from tbl_"+font+" where format(fw,'.###')='"+fw+"' and code='" + code + "'";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
         while (rs.next()) {
            character = rs.getString(1);
            return character;
        }
        statement.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        return "";
    }
    return "";   
}
```

Comment: I think you get an exception. Please add `ex.printstacktrace()' in your `catch`  block to see whats happend.

Comment: There is no exception just don't return result(no match found)

Comment: @user3649116 How do you know there is no exception? Your catch block only has `return ""`, which is exactly the same thing you do when there is no result.

Answer (score 2):

Access SQL queries that are run *from within the Access application itself* can use a wide variety of VBA functions that may not be available (or may behave a bit differently) in Access SQL queries that are run from other applications.

As a workaround, I would suggest this:

```java
String query = String.format(
        "select character from tbl_%s " +
        "where Trunc((Val(fw)*1000)+0.5)=? and code=?", 
        font);
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setInt(1, (int)(1000 * Double.parseDouble(fw)));  // e.g. 48143
ps.setString(2, code);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

### Edit re: comments

As explained by jamadei, the `Format()` function as implemented in UCanAccess versions <= 2.0.6.2 produces slightly different results than the Access/VBA implementation for this particular case. Specifically `Format(48.1425,".###)` returns `48.143` in an Access query but it returns `48.142` in a UCanAccess query. <strike>This may be corrected in a future release of UCanAccess.</strike> This has been corrected in UCanAccess 2.0.6.3.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Mr Gord i will try it

Comment: I can use `Format()` in a query with VBScript and Access 2007.  I don't understand why it would not be available to queries run from Java or .NET.

Comment: @HansUp This person is using [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) in their Java application and `Format()` won't work under that configuration. Still, you're right: I should adjust the wording of my answer.

Comment: OK, I don't understand UCanAccess ... I expected it to hand off a statement to the Access db engine ... but apparently something else/more is going on.  And apparently UCanAccess translates `Trunc()` to something Access supports ... is that right?  I should probably just avoid this Java stuff since I don't know squat about it. ;-)

Comment: @HansUp Yes, UCanAccess apparently supports `Trunc()` but not `Int()`. I discovered that when I was testing my code before posting it. UCanAccess uses [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) to read from and write to the Access database. No ACE/Jet is involved; it even works on Linux and Mac.

Comment: Aha, "No ACE/Jet is involved"!  No wonder I'm lost.  Thanks, GT.

Comment: In the format function implementation, when a pattern like '.###' is specified instead of a specific format like 'fixed', 'standard' and so on, UCanaccess delegates to DecimalFormat.format the formatting.  This last method, in this very specific and "on the line" case, returns the string 48.142 and not 48.143 as Access does.  If the number were 48.14251, all would work  as well as in Access. I'm thinking of a generic way to solve this issue.

Comment: @GordThompson Int function is supported by UCanAccess but it doesn't work in your example because my implementation returns a short instead of an Integer: I'll fix it in the 2.0.6.3. providing a different UCanAccess implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Both the mentioned issues(int function and rounding mode "half up" in the format function) have been fixed in the 2.0.6.3.